# Calling secured API from NodeJS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, identityserver4

I have an API that is secured using OAuth (IdentityServer 4).  I need to call this from an AWS Lambda function.  I cant figure out how to do this in Node (noob to node).  I can see an example of using oidc-client package but it seems to be designed for browser based clients.  I just need the access token to call the api.  Ive done this from a .Net console app, but Im lost in Node.  Does anyone know of an example of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I would say to check out Passport JS: http://www.passportjs.org/.

I'd also like to link to the open source Passport strategy for IdentityServer4: https://github.com/kelvintang2000/passport-oauth2-ids4

Answer (score 0):

@Jonesie have you tried example from AWS repository? Request you to take a look https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/tree/master/examples/apps/api-gateway-authorizer-nodejs

Comment: Thanks, but I dont think that's really what I need.  I dont use API Gateway as my API is in fargate.  All I really want in the end is to schedule a call to a resource in the API.  I thought a lambda would be the simplest thing here... wrong!